# Aplicar filtro después de msgbox ACCES

Tags: vba, ms-access

Buen día, estoy intentando aplicar unos filtros en una tabla de acces, cuando hago el filtro sin mostrar msgbox el filtro funciona pero si uso mensajes antes del filtro este ya no se aplica y la tabla no abre, la idea es que se aplique un filtro dependiendo de una variable (esto ya esta hecho) y que el usuario pueda elegir si aplicar o no el filtro, adjunto el codigo:

```
    Confirma = MsgBox("Tiene " & cantidad & " soportes pendientes " & vbNewLine & "¿Dese Filtrar Sus Soportes Pendientes?", vbYesNo, "Soportes Pendientes")
If Confirma = vbYes Then
    If sSede = "Bogota" Then
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[SAP]![Sede]=""Bogota D.C."" And [SAP]![Grabador]=""" & sUsuarioActivo & """ And [SAP]![Estado_Soporte]=""Incompleto"" Or [SAP]![Estado_Soporte]=""Pendiente""", ""
    Else
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[SAP]![Sede]=""Medellin"" Or [SAP]![Sede]=""Cali"" And [SAP]![Grabador]=""" & sUsuarioActivo & """ And [SAP]![Estado_Soporte]=""Incompleto"" Or [SAP]![Estado_Soporte]=""Pendiente""", ""
    End If
Else
            If sSede = "Bogota" Then
         DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[SAP]![Sede]=""Bogota D.C.""", ""
    Else
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[SAP]![Sede]=""Medellin"" Or [SAP]![Sede]=""Cali""", ""
    End If
End If
```

Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: A que te referis con que no se aplica? no pasa siquiera por el else? que es lo que pasa exactamente?

Comment: El código está en un formulario en el evento open, si pasa por el else, ya que lo he intentado comentado el filtro y mostrando otro mensaje, pero el formulario simplemente no abre, el filtro lo he probado sin el msgbox y si funciona

Comment: Por favor aclara la version de access.. porque luego de navegar un poco para verificar tu error veo que hay problemas disparando un msgbox en el open del form...

Comment: Estoy usando Acces 2016 de 64bits